# Trouble sending custom post data; str object has no attribute items

Tags: python, html, post, header, cloudflare

Hey so when i attempt to send custom headers in post data I recieve the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'
```

And this is the custom headers that I am attempting to send...

```
Headers="""{
":authority":"coinmarketcap.com",
":method":"POST",
":scheme":"https",
"accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8",
"accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate, br",
"accept-language":"en-US,en;q=0.9",
"cache-control":"max-age=0",
"content-length":"743",
"content-type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
"cookie":\""""+Cookie+"""\",
"origin":"https://coinmarketcap.com",
"referer":"https://coinmarketcap.com",
"upgrade-insecure-requests":"1",
"user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.186 Safari/537.36", 
}"""
```

When I attempt to send the headers that I get directly from a get request, cloudflare gives me a 400 Bad Request error. Even after setting up cfscrape and running it through that..

Answer (score 0):

Your headers string should probably be a dict, whatever you’re passing that to is expecting a non string data type for sure.